# How do I set display:inline-block on my addClass()

Tags: jquery

How do I set my span will be `display:inline-block`

```
$("#checking").fadeTo(200, 0.1, function ()
 {
  $(this).html('Username is not available').addClass('cross').fadeTo(900, 1);
});
```

Current output

```
<span style="display: inline; opacity: 1;" id="checking" class="cross">Username is not available</span>
```

In CSS I have set the cross class is `inline-block`.

Let me know how to make the `style="display: inline; opacity: 1;"` will be `style="inline-display: inline; opacity: 1;"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To set the CSS properties of a element, you can just use the `css()` function:

```
$('#foo').css('display', 'inline-block');
```

So in your case, just throw `css()` into that chain:

```
$(this).html('Username is not available').addClass('cross').css('display', 'inline-block').fadeTo(900, 1)
```